# How to pass variables into a 'sub' block?

Tags: perl

How can I pass on a variable into a Perl sub block?

(This is a perl CGI page.)

The variable $yellow is not passed onto the sub login block... 
I read somewhere that it's not supposed to, though it can be done. How can I pass the variable onto the sub block?

For example:

```
    $cgi = new CGI;
    $yellow = $cgi->param("yellow");

sub login {
### code .....
$yellow .....
### code....
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to code the login function to take a parameter:

```
sub login {
    my($arg1) = @_;
    ...
}
```

And then when you call the function, just pass the parameter:

```
login($yellow);
```

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be very unfamiliar with Perl. I suggest that a quick look at the documentation would have served you better, but here goes.

There is no Perl *'sub' block*. Perl has subroutines like most other languages (although they may want to call them *functions* or perhaps *methods*).

A Perl subroutine accepts an *array* of arguments from the built-in array called `@_`. You could access it directly, but it is usually best if you leave it alone and copy its contents to scalar variables local to the subroutine.

In your case, my guess is that you should write something like

```
my $cgi = CGI->new;
my $colour = $cgi->param('yellow');

login($colour);

sub login {
  my ($colour) = @_;

  # code using passed $colour
}
```